# Is it possible to do a SLIDER with UL/LI and NO IMAGES?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So was looking on google for slider tutorials, I have found loads, but all for images. I wanted to know if it was possible to do a slider with ul elements, with no images.

UL has width of 300px, for example, and I have 3 LI elements, each one 300px width and with a diferent background color.

Is it possible to do a slider with just that?

It's hard to find...

I'm a newbie with sliders...! lol

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/mCze7/)**

Slider as per your requirements and added autoplay

HTML

```
<h1>Slider</h1>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">>></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>

<div class="slider_option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #58DDAF;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like an easy one to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is definitely possible with any number of slider plugins, but my personal favorite is:

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel

From the description on the site:

> You don't need any special markup. All you need is to wrap your divs(owl works with any type element) inside the container element . Class "owl-carousel" is mandatory to apply proper styles that come from owl.carousel.css file.

Once you load the proper assets, including two css files and the javascript plugin itself you can just create your markup as so:

```
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  ...
</div>
```

But you're not limited to any specific element. It's a touch enabled slider too so it works great on mobile devices.

EDIT: Here's a codepen I forked from an example with a `<ul><li>` combo and different colored bkgds.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mcgKn

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [swipejs](https://github.com/thebird/Swipe). It requires `div`s instead of `li`s but works well cross browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I do it all the time Using FlexSlide. Its also responsive, I highly recommend this:

**http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/**

Its also quick and easy to use. And you can use anything inside of it.