# Slide the li elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created the look of a slider with HTML and CSS. Now I need to slide it with JavaScript.

```js
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Slide it
})
```

```css
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 500px;
}

#slideshow ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  height: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slideshow ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: orange;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: orange;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" id="prev">&lt;</a>
  <a href="#" id="next">&gt;</a>
</div>
```

I have no idea how to slide it. I already tried it with `document.querySelector('li').style.left = '500px';` but that wouldn't work.

No plugins and no jQuery, vanilla JS only!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to do a SLIDER with UL/LI and NO IMAGES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170668/is-it-possible-to-do-a-slider-with-ul-li-and-no-images)

Comment: Just a suggestion, you could use tiny slider: https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. So far all you have is a click listener. Nobody is going to build this slider for you here...that is far too much to expect

Comment: @charlietfl I didn't ask for someone to do it for me. I just need to know HOW I could do it. That's why I don't need any plugins or jQuery, since I would like to learn it. I don't need the whole code, tips would be enough.

Comment: Well this also isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service. There are 100's of open source slider scripts you could explore code in and also lots of tutorials around on the web.

Comment: Take a few minutes to read through the [help] to get a better understanding of how this site does work and what is expected when asking and what is off topic

Comment: @charlietfl sure, there are tons of tutorials but I don't want to change my HTML and CSS!

Comment: Fine but that doesn't mean you can't adapt from other sources. Adding additional restrictions on your requirements is going in the wrong direction for help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the li elements you can see that they are stacking in vertical order, so they are way below what the user can see. It works with position:absolute, see my example.

I added a transition CSS line to all the li elements. Then only the element that has the "active" css class is in the right spot. All other elements are shifted 500px to the left.

```js
var currentSlide = "slide1"
var nextSlide = "slide2"

document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Slide it
  var ele = document.getElementById(currentSlide);
  removeClass(ele, "active");
  ele = document.getElementById(nextSlide);
  addClass(ele, "active");

  if (currentSlide === "slide1") {
    currentSlide = nextSlide;
    nextSlide = "slide3";
  } else if (currentSlide === "slide2") {
    currentSlide = nextSlide;
    nextSlide = "slide4";
  } else if (currentSlide === "slide3") {
    currentSlide = nextSlide;
    nextSlide = "slide1";
  } else if (currentSlide === "slide4") {
    currentSlide = nextSlide;
    nextSlide = "slide2";
  }

})

/* helpers */

function addClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList)
    el.classList.add(className)
  else if (!hasClass(el, className)) el.className += " " + className
}

function removeClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList)
    el.classList.remove(className)
  else if (hasClass(el, className)) {
    var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)')
    el.className = el.className.replace(reg, ' ')
  }
}
```

```css
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 500px;
}

#slideshow ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  height: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slideshow ul li {
  transition: 1s;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  left: -500px;
}

.active {
  left: 0px!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <ul>
    <li id="slide1" class="active">SLIDE 1</li>
    <li id="slide2" style="background: orange;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li id="slide3" style="background: red;">SLIDE 3</li>
    <li id="slide4" style="background: green">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" id="prev">&lt;</a>
  <a href="#" id="next">&gt;</a>
</div>
```